# Is there a way to convert csv data to a Matlab timetable using Python or Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, csv, timetable

I would like to know how to make a Matlab timetable from this data:

```
               date   time     open     high      low    close tickvol
0        2011.01.02  17:01   1.3342   1.3344   1.3341   1.3341       0
1        2011.01.02  17:02   1.3343   1.3343   1.3343   1.3343       0
2        2011.01.02  17:03   1.3344   1.3344   1.3344   1.3344       0
3        2011.01.02  17:06   1.3345   1.3349   1.3345   1.3348       0
4        2011.01.02  17:07   1.3346   1.3346   1.3346   1.3346       0
...             ...    ...      ...      ...      ...      ...     ...
4558998  2023.05.19  16:54  1.08051  1.08057  1.08046  1.08046       0
4558999  2023.05.19  16:55  1.08047  1.08055  1.08042  1.08054       0
4559000  2023.05.19  16:56  1.08053  1.08058   1.0805  1.08055       0
4559001  2023.05.19  16:57  1.08055   1.0806  1.08048  1.08056       0
4559002  2023.05.19  16:58  1.08055  1.08057  1.08055  1.08057       0
```

Not much idea of matlab, and don't know what to do with python to leave correct the data.

What can I do to make this happen?

Edited:

I've tried with this:

```
TT=readtimetable('EURUSD_big_data.csv')
```

but this error appears:

```
Expected a datetime or duration variable to use as RowTimes. Check that the data can
be converted to datetime or duration, or supply a "TimeStep" or "SampleRate".
```

how to I use

```
 TimeStep
```

in this example?

Comment: Have you tried https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtimetable.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have what looks like a big [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) [*DataFrame*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), you can use [`mfinance`](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance). I will plot a dataset found in the docs (*that matches the format of yours but with more rows to select just a portion/period of time -- by using [partial string indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing)*--) to have a meaningful visualization.

```py
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf #pip install mplfinance

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/matplotlib/" \
      "mplfinance/master/examples/data/SP500_NOV2019_IDay.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

a_period = df.loc["2019-11-06 15:00":"2019-11-06 16:00", :]

mpf.plot(a_period, type="candle", mav=(7,12))
```

Output :

[image]

*Dataset/Period used :*

```
print(a_period)

                       Open   Close    High     Low  Volume
Date                                                       
2019-11-06 15:00:00 3075.25 3074.57 3075.25 3074.57       0
2019-11-06 15:01:00 3074.55 3074.49 3074.70 3074.30       0
2019-11-06 15:02:00 3074.48 3074.24 3074.56 3074.21       0
...                     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2019-11-06 15:58:00 3075.49 3075.54 3075.98 3075.49       0
2019-11-06 15:59:00 3075.69 3076.75 3076.79 3075.55       0
2019-11-06 16:00:00 3076.74 3076.73 3076.74 3076.72       0

[61 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: **NB** : In your case, you need to add an extra step right after reading your  `.csv` file as a *DataFrame*: `df = pd.read_csv("EURUSD_big_data.csv", sep=",") #change the sep if needed;df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.pop("date").str.cat(df.pop("time"), sep=" "))`.

Answer (score 0):

In matlab, it can be solved by using

```
table2timetable()
```

First you have to make a DataFrame in python, set the time to date time:

```
data["Time"]= pd.to_datetime(data["Time"],unit='s')
```

after this, you have to index time

```
data.set_index(data["Time"],inplace=True)
```

and pass the df to csv

```
data.to_csv(str(symbol)+".csv")
```

Once you have a csv, in matlab

read the csv and make it table

```
prices=readtable("EURUSD.csv")
```

make the table a timetebale

```
prices=table2timetable(prices)
```

& drop the NaN rows

```
prices=rmmissing(prices)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a lot of complexity around this. Write a CSV file with a time column and read it into matlab

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtimetable.html (may die at some time...)

Edit:

Taken what you have tried. you have OUTPUT the index column of your dataframe. That is being read in as your datetime column to the timetable. Remove that column manually (more painful) or change your output code so that it does not save the index column - which I assume here is fallacious anyway.

You may also need to combine your date and time columns into a datetime column using the datetime library or similar - or as timestamps/epochs.

Note also that table2timetable will NOT solve your problem since you do NOT have a column that works as sampling rate, timestamp, datetime, etc... You will have to fix your dataset output format FIRST, and then you can fix use either

```
readtimetable('file.csv')
```

or

```
table2timetabel('file.csv', 'RowTimes', timeVarName)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34444412)

Comment: @wohlstad I understand what you are say - makes sense. I think this post would better have done a google search on timetables as others and read the documentation?

Comment: I am actually not familiar with this specific subject. I got to your answer via the review queues. It was probabaly triggered because your original answer was not a lot more than a link.

Comment: @wohlstad make sense. Updated it accordingly.